# Hard disk usage

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 64 bit in my laptop. I used the entire disk (500 GB). Now the disk looks like this:

1. Filesystem partition1 496GB ext4
2. Extended partition2 4.3GB
3. Swap partition5 4.3GB
4. Free space 1.1MB

To the best of my knowledge, there should have been only two partition, incl. swap. I had Kubuntu installed previously. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: The actual output of `fdisk -l` would be more helpful. Or a screenshot of `gparted`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case there ARE only two partitions - the first 496GB partition and the Extended Partition.

Within the Extended Partition are *volumes* (not partitions - you can't have partitions within partitions). In this case you have a swap volume only plus some free space.

I recommend doing the following setup in future:

1. Partition 1 of no less than 20GB for just the root "/" filesystem.
   This is where the OS and your installed applications will go to and system updates are also cached here. If you are going to install lots of apps, perhaps bump this up to 50GB or more.
2. Partition 2 of no less than 2GB for "swap", aka virtual memory. If you have 8GB or more
   RAM, then don't bother with swap - you'll never touch it with so
   much RAM in your system, so save the space and use it for something
   else. The installer will complain, but you can tell it to ignore and continue.
3. Partition 3 will be the remainder of the drive for the home "/home"
   filesystem. This is where your personal data is stored and
   physically keeps it separate from the OS. In the event you need to
   reinstall the OS, you can do so by telling the installer to format
   the root filesystem but to preserve the home partition. No data
   lost.

You are able to create one more partition be it a partition or extended volume. If you believe you need more than four partitions, then setup the extended partition and make as many volumes as you need inside it.

Once you become more advanced, however, consider looking at Logical Volume Management (LVM) instead of traditional partitioning. It's very cool.

Comment: The usual phrasing is "logical partition," and in that sense, the extended partition *does* hold (logical) partitions. The problem with referring to these as logical volumes is that this is the same terminology used by Linux's [Logical Volume Manager (LVM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29) subsystem, which is entirely different from extended and logical partitions. Thus, using "logical volume" to refer to logical partitions creates confusion. Fortunately, the whole primary/extended/logical nonsense is going away with GPT partitioning.

Answer (score 3):

On MBR (or MSDOS) partition tables, there are three types of partitions:

- Primary
- Extended

  - Logical

Operating systems like Windows can only be installed on primary partitions. Linux doesn't usually care.

Only four primary partitions can be made, and only one extended partition can be made at the expense of one primary partition. If four primary partitions exist, no more partitions can be added without deleting an existing partition first. 
So the default behaviour of Ubuntu's installer is to create an extended partition if none existed. When using the whole disk, it uses one primary for `/` (and one for `/boot` if LVM was used) and creates one extended partition with  a logical partition for swap.